# Putting islandora results in a view or block

Tags: search, drupal, view, solr, islandora

I am new to islandora. I have it integrated with solr and it works fine but the results only show on the page with the following URL:

somesite.com/islandora/search

This is fine but I would like the results to show on a different page inside a view or a block.

Is this actually possible?

After reading the documentation it doesn't seem like it is. But I believe this should be a rather slandered requirement.

I have tried using URL Aliases, with no luck.

Has anyone done this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have integrated the apache solr with sit Search then there is a module named [Search API Page Block](https://drupal.org/project/search_api_page_block), which can help you showing result in block but it will only work for title of the nodes.

As it explains -

> Currently, this module is only useful when placing search result
>   blocks on node pages, since it currently only uses $node->title as the
>   search keywords. Future development can lead to other uses, including
>   using Taxonomy terms, Context module, or custom fields to set the
>   keywords.